# Creating a for loop to check spans id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a for loop that loops seven times. It will check my outer spans id to see if the innermost span contains the static number 1.
this is what I had tried to do

```
for (var i=0; i<8; i++) {
   var mySpans = $('mySpan'+i);         

    if ($(this).find('mySpans.span').text() == '1') {
        alert("found");       }
}
```

HTML

```
<span class="spanClass" id="mySpan1">
  <div>
    <span class="innerSpanClass"> </span>
  </div>
</span>

<span class="spanClass" id="mySpan2">
  <div>
    <span class="innerSpanClass"> </span>
  </div>
</span>

<span class="spanClass" id="mySpan3">
  <div>
    <span class="innerSpanClass"> </span>
  </div>
</span>

<span class="spanClass" id="mySpan4">
  <div>
    <span class="innerSpanClass"> </span>
  </div>
</span>

<span class="spanClass" id="mySpan5">
  <div>
    <span class="innerSpanClass"> </span>
  </div>
</span>

<span class="spanClass" id="mySpan6">
  <div>
    <span class="innerSpanClass">1</span>
  </div>
</span>

<span class="spanClass" id="mySpan7">
  <div>
    <span class="innerSpanClass">2</span>
  </div>
</span>
```

thanks a bunch

Comment: There is no method `getElementsById`, the correct name is `getElementById` (singular, not plural). But why are you using this if you're using jQuery?

Comment: sorry Im trying to create a calender, I need the loop the check through the first 7 days(or master spans) to check if the innermost span has the text "1".

Comment: If you post a live demo it would probably clarify the question.

Comment: (http://jsfiddle.net/MSKMN/2/)
This is what it looks like so far

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you can grab all your spans first with a selector, then filter what you need, and count the items that were found:

```
var $result = $('.spanClass .innerSpanClass').filter(function() {
  return $.trim($(this).text()) == '1';
});

if ($result.length) alert('found');
```

Comment: hmm thanks but I dont think this is what I am looking for. I need the for loop to check the outer spans Id mySpan(1-7). then using an if statement to check that one of the innermost span has the number 1

Comment: Your question is still not very clear but it seems you just need to narrow down the collection: `$('.spanClass .innerSpanClass').slice(0,6).filter(...)`. Check the jQuery manual and go through the methods that you can apply to collections. Why use `for` loops when you're using jQuery?

Comment: *"I need the for loop to check the outer spans Id mySpan(1-7). then using an if statement to check that one of the innermost span has the number 1."* - okay, *why?* That approach is far more expensive than the answer posted here. What restrictions/requirements are you operating under?

Comment: This is for a project, the criteria is that I use a for loop